# Opening Fox Pro files in Excel 2016 or Access 2016

Tags: excel, visual-foxpro, dbf

This site has been so incredibly helpful in navigating R and SQL so I thought that this would be worth a try.

I have a series of files that were created in Visual Fox Pro 6. In Fox Pro, they were created by going file>Export>Delimited File. When I go to the folder, they are classified as .dbf files. My current computer operates Microsoft Office 2016 and Windows 10.

When I attempt to open the files in Access or Excel, it says "not in expected format" and if one continues, they are gibberish. They can't be opened via Notepad++ either.

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: A .dbf file is Foxpro's native format. If you exported them as delimited, they'd probably show up as a .csv file. Are you sure you're looking in the right folder, or at the right file?

Comment: If you used the Export Wizard as described above, you should have a TXT file with whatever name you specified.

Comment: Delimited files are plain text files. And, any file could be opened in Notepad++ (or even Notepad) - though might not be a good idea for binary files. Instead of "exporting" you could directly import from excel or access (who would want to open in access is another matter).

Comment: @HerbWolfe, Excel 2016 and older versions (at least back to excel 2007)  always had support for reading dbf files. Using OLEDB or ODBC is "direct" support in my book and could either be done from excel menus or writing a VBA macro. I don't think something you might simply do with menus is an indirect support. With VFP6 tables it is even easier because there is also ODBC driver for VFP6 version tables (even Access could then do "import").